# Sharing my GCP pub/sub topic with customer to publish

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am working on an assignment where our customers will sync their crm data to our systems. The sync will be ongoing process. Any best practices or suggestions on google pub/sub for sharing one of our existing (or a new one) topic that our customer will publish too and we consume? Idea here is to keep sync asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the other party the `roles/pubsub.publisher` role for your specific project if you own the topic. Alternatively, if they own the topic, they can grant you the role `roles/pubsub.subscriber` which will let you subscribe to that topic.

For more information, see [Access Control](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control)

Answer (score 1):

@Alex-hong is true if your customer is on GCP. If not, you have 2 solutions:

- You can generate a service account and send it the JSON key file. Define the right role on the service account (as described by Alex) and let your customer use the Service Account and to publish to the PubSub topic. This solution implies an important development by your customer (Use external JSON key, use new libraries to push messages,...)
- You can deploy a Cloud Function/Cloud Run endpoint and let your customer to simply perform an HTTP request. Of course, you can secure the call with Basic Authentication or APIkey (or something like that, that you check in your Cloud Function). The function only check the security and publish to PubSub. It's often simpler and more standard for your customer.

*On the last point, it could be possible to set up an [ESP](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp) in place of the function, but I never tested for publishing directly to PubSub.*